# "193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application" bug with a new Rails Application

Tags: mysql, windows, ruby, windows-7

I have a new rails application which I have created under Windows 7 by going into a directory and typing "rails newapp". The creation went fine, and when I access the root page, all is well. However, when I try to access a page that would access the database, I get this:

```
193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

In the developer.log. Mysql is running fine on my machine, and I have other applications which I have running in here in other directories, it's just this one that doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm also having this issue. If you found out what happened, please post. I'll do the same if/when I find out.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's the answer that worked for me. Turns out it was an issue of x64 vs. x32 issue and Rails 2.3.2.

The answer I got from here (http://osdir.com/ml/RubyonRailsTalk/2009-06/msg01775.html):

> In case anyone else has the same
>   problem after a lot of struggling on
>   my Windows XP x64 machine, with MySQL
>   5.1.30 (x64) and Rails 2.3.2 installed, this above suggestiong
>   helped me.
>        Download libMySql.dll from here (http://instantrails.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk/InstantRails-win/InstantRails/mysql/bin/)
>   and putting it in ruby\bin solved the
>   problem.

Comment: The linked-to solution appears to be a hack.  I'm not happy with solutions that seem like black magic.  Couldn't this really be a problem with using the 64 bit version of MySQL with Rails (or maybe just with WEBrick)?  I'm going to continue experimenting by downloading and installing the 32 bit version of MySQL instead of mixing in a DLL from the version in the InstantRails bundle.

Comment: It's a hack to be sure - it's because MySQL support for Windows is spotty at best.

Comment: great!! this had been around for almost a year!! but why Ruby never fix this up? I'm still having the problem... GRRRR

Comment: This solution appears to be out of date now.

Comment: It is, steps from this tutorial made it work for me: http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/

Answer (score 6):

Solved by following the directions on this blog here: http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/

which involves using the non installer version of the MySQL Connector http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

I could not get webrick to run on x64 Windows 7 system -- got the same error

"193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application”

If I just replaced the file libmysql.dll (as suggested in posts above), I got a different error.

"Incorrect MySQL client library version!"

My Path set like this: C:\Ruby187\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Ruby187\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\rails-3.1.1\bin

(didn't need to change the path again)

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs if you have a file with name "Program" in the root of your drive. Say for example you are trying to execute "C:\Program Files\SomeApp\Bin\SomeExe.Exe" it tries to execute "C:\Program"  if it exists. In some situations a file with this name get created if you forget to quote "C:\Program Files..." with some commandline commands. This of course also applies for you D: drive, etc.

This error often occurs if you try to start services, but may occur in other situations.

Simply deleting the file C:\Program or D:\Program etc. solves the problem.

Comment: Hi--- this wasn't the problem for me, since I don't have a program like that on the root of my drive.

Answer (score 0):

Having run into multiple issues setting up MySQL with Rails on Windows x64 my recommendations are:

- Install the 32-bit version of MySQL, do not try to use the 64-bit version.
- Install into a path with no spaces, do not accept a default like "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\"
- Install the MySQL gem with an invocation similar to:

  ```
       gem install mysql -- --platform=ruby --with-mysql-dir="D:\Programs\MySQL\MySQL-Server-5.5" --with-libmysqllib="D:\Programs\MySQL\MySQL-Server-5.5\lib\"
  ```
- Be sure to uninstall/reinstall the gem whenever you install a new version of MySQL.
- Make sure D:\Programs\MySQL\MySQL-Server-5.5\lib is included in your path, as well as D:\Programs\MySQL\MySQL-Server-5.5\bin. Make sure other copies of libmysql.dll are not being picked up from elsewhere on your path or your ruby installation directories.

This worked for me with mysql-5.5.15-win32, mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32 and Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Umm, no it doesn't, this just gets past the "not a valid Win32...", it still segfaults on db:create, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020152/rake-dbcreate-failing-on-win7-x64  This is definitely broken, copied the libMySql.dll from InstantRails like everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file libmysql.dll from your MySQL installation directory and paste it into your Ruby installation's bin directory. You may need to download a zip archive from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ if your MySQL installation directory doesn't already include the file libmysql.dll.

Answer (score -2):

Using Ruby (1.8.7) with MySQL(5.5) on Windows 7 and also getting error 193.
**Copying the [libmySQL.dll](http://instantrails.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk/InstantRails-win/InstantRails/mysql/bin/) to ruby /bin worked fine for me.**

```
C:\Work\redmine-2.4.1\config\database.yml content:

# Default setup is given for MySQL with ruby1.9. If you're running Redmine
# with MySQL and ruby1.8, replace the adapter name with `mysql`.
# Examples for PostgreSQL, SQLite3 and SQL Server can be found at the end.
# Line indentation must be 2 spaces (no tabs).

production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: redmine
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: "pwd@123"
  encoding: utf8
```