# Getting Rails running on Win7 x64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7, rake

My development machine used to be a Vista Home box but I switched to Win7 Pro yesterday and I am trying to get everything set up again. I'm trying to get RoR working again with my Win7 install (yeah I know, should really use something besides Windows) and it's spitting the following error out at me when I try to rake db:drop/create/etc.

```
193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.   

/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32/lib/1.9/mysql_api.so
```

I read [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208029/193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-bug-with-a-new-rails-application) SO post and did recall doing something to this effect when I installed rails on the Vista box. Instead of grabbing the file the guy linked to I went to my MySQL installation and grabbed and pasted the libmySQL.dll sitting in there to my Ruby installation. I did restart afterwords. What else should I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, but a suggestion that might be suitable: VMWare/Virtualbox with a linux image. Turnkey rails might be a place to start, but their release is a bit old.

It's not like you were planning to deploy your apps on Windows anyway(!), so Samba for file sharing and PuTTy for console, there's no need for the headache of trying to running and maintaining Rails on Windows. As a bonus, you get things like git and ssh for free.

Comment: I'll accept your answer just so that I don't accept my own. Also, because before I came back on here today I did just this haha.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use one of the new [installer](http://railsinstaller.org/) packages which should, like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html), make your life a lot easier.

It's by the same guy that made the Ruby Version Manager [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) which works fantastically well in other environments.

Answer (score 0):

tadman's solution may work but I wasn't able to try it out. Will keep it in mind for future use. What I ultimately went with was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208029/193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-bug-with-a-new-rails-application) solution.