# rake db:create failing on Win7 x64

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, windows-7

**Updated to include trace info**

I'm setting up a Win7 machine for Ruby on Rails development and seem to have run into an issue with my rake tasks. When I call rake db: create the cmd window sits for a *very* long time and dumps the following:

```
C:\my\directory\rails>rake db:create --trace
(in C:/my/directory/rails)
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:create
foo already exists
foo already exists
C:/Ruby192/bin/rake: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25) [i386-mingw32]

-- control frame ----------
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:000b24 d:000b24 TOP
---------------------------

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html


This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

What does this mean? I am running Win7 Pro x64, MySQL 5.5, and Rails 3.

Comment: What is the output if you run it with `--trace`?

Comment: I've updated the above to reflect what trace gives me

Comment: What's `foo`?  If it's a table, the error might be due to your database already being partially created, in which case you should look at using `rake db:reset` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was the dll that was faulty. Used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208029/193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-bug-with-a-new-rails-application) approach.