# How do I get Ruby's DBI gem properly installed so that it can talk to MySql?

Tags: ruby, installation, dbi

On my Windows 7 box, I've installed Ruby 1.9.2, and installed the following gems:

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

- dbd-mysql (0.4.4)
- dbi (0.4.5)
- deprecated (2.0.1)
- httparty (0.8.1)
- rubygems-update (1.8.15)

(I did this using gem install).

I have also written the following simple test harness:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'dbi'

begin
    dbh = DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:test", "username", "pwd")

    row = dbh.select_one("SELECT VERSION()")
    puts "Server Version: "+row[0]
rescue DBI::DatabaseError => e
    puts "An error occurred"
    puts "Error code: #{e.err}"
    puts "Error message: #{e.errstr}"
ensure
    # disconnect from server
    dbh.disconnect if dbh
end
```

Regardless of how I specify the connection string, I keep getting:

```
C:\Code\Concordance.SE>ruby test_sql.rb
C:/Tools/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:300:in `block in
load_driver': Unable to load driver 'Mysql' (underlying error: uninitialized con
stant DBI::DBD::Mysql) (DBI::InterfaceError)
        from C:/Tools/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'

        from C:/Tools/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:242:
in `load_driver'
        from C:/Tools/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:160:
in `_get_full_driver'
        from C:/Tools/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:145:
in `connect'
        from test_sql.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (Obviously I'm not sharing my real username or pwd :)

Comment: As a tip for making your life easier, I'd recommend using one of Ruby's ORMs rather than the DBI interface. [ActiveRecord](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/), which is part of Rails, can be used separately, and [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/), which is my favorite, is a standalone. The benefit to an ORM is you gain SQL generation that is well written, and can easily move from one DBM to another without worrying about changing your SQL.

Comment: For what its worth I ran your code verbatim successfully on linux, with the same versions of dbi, dbd-mysql, and deprecated.  It worked both with and without requiring rubygems.  I seem to recall some initial heartache when I installed dbi, I'll poke around and see if I can see if my issues were related to yours.

Comment: Is `test` the name of your host or of the database?

Comment: What happens if you run this command: `ruby -rmysql -e 'p Mysql::VERSION'`?  If that command fails, then you may need to install/fix the mysql gem.

Comment: @forforf Output to this as follows: C:\Code\Concordance.SE>gem install mysql
Successfully installed mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32...
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32...

Comment: C:\Code\Concordance.SE>ruby -rmysql -e 'p Mysql::VERSION'
C:/Tools/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.   - C:/Tools/Ruby192/lib/ruby/ge
ms/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32/lib/1.9/mysql_api.so (LoadError)
        from C:/Tools/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.r
b:36:in `require'
        from mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32/l
ib/mysql.rb:7:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Tools/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'

Comment: @theTinMan test was the last iteration I tried :)  The database is actually called 'Concordance' and its on localhost, so I had tried variations of 'DBD:MySql:localhost:concordance'

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my problem in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208029/193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-bug-with-a-new-rails-application).

When you are running Ruby on a 64 bit operating system, you need to copy a new version of libMySql.dll into the Ruby\bin directory.  The best source for that dll is [here](http://instantrails.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk/InstantRails-win/InstantRails/mysql/bin/).

Comment: So the answer to my initial question, as is so often the case, 'What am I doing wrong?' is "You're using Windows!"

Comment: Glad you got it solved. Using DBI can be a bit of a pain, but it's sometimes helpful to have a low level interface that the other ORMs don't provide.