# Ruby and C-tree Database Integration

Tags: sql, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to write a Ruby wrapper to interact with the C-Tree database from Faircom. The problem I am facing is that when I try to connect to the database

**LOCAL GEMS**

```
dbd-odbc (0.2.5)
dbi (0.4.5)
deprecated (2.0.1)
```

**CODE**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'dbi'

begin
    dbh = DBI.connect("DBI:ODBC:FAIRCOM", "username", "pwd")
    row = dbh.select_one("SELECT VERSION()")
    puts "Server Version: "+row[0]
rescue DBI::DatabaseError => e
    puts "An error occurred"
    puts "Error code: #{e.err}"
    puts "Error message: #{e.errstr}"
ensure
    # disconnect from server
    dbh.disconnect if dbh
end
```

is throwing an error saying unable to load driver. Has anyone successfully established a connection to a C-Tree database in Ruby and if yes can you please share how?

The error i receive is this one

```
An error occurred
Error code:
Error message: IM003 (0) [iODBC][Driver Manager]Specified driver could not be loaded
```

I am using the same code from the other DBI post, but the issue is still persisting.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question.  The answer to the question you asked is either "yes" or "no," and the most likely answer is yes.

Comment: What exactly is the error message that you're getting? Possibly related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841974/how-do-i-get-rubys-dbi-gem-properly-installed-so-that-it-can-talk-to-mysql

Comment: mbratch: i updated the post with the error message and i read the post  you mentioned but the issue is still not solved. I am using MAC OSX and i am not sure if that is an issue or not.