# custom_require.rb:36:in `require': 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just installed rails using Rails installer.

and when I ran the following code:

```
rails new blog
```

I got the following errors:

```
F:/dev/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_re
quire.rb:36:in `require': 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.   - F:/dev/r
uby/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/digest/md5.so (LoadErro
r)
        from F:/dev/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubyg
ems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from F:/dev/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railt
ies-3.2.1/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from F:/dev/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubyg
ems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from F:/dev/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubyg
ems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from F:/dev/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railt
ies-3.2.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:1:in `<top (required)>
'
        from F:/dev/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubyg
ems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from F:/dev/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubyg
ems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from F:/dev/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railt
ies-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
        from F:/dev/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubyg
ems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from F:/dev/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubyg
ems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from F:/dev/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railt
ies-3.2.1/lib/rails/cli.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from F:/dev/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubyg
ems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from F:/dev/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubyg
ems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from F:/dev/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railt
ies-3.2.1/bin/rails:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from F:/dev/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rails:19:in `load'
        from F:/dev/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'
```

I'm running on ruby193 and rails 3.2.1

Any thoughts on how to solve this ?

Comment: Did you look here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208029/193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-bug-with-a-new-rails-application?rq=1 Are you using 64bit Windows?

Comment: how come this issue related to Mysql ?