# When in start my rails server i can face some errors in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Today i installed ruby and rails gems everthing got success

but after when i tried to start server using command rails server i get some error it is being listed below please help me

```
C:\Ruby200-x64\project>rails server
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `requir
e': 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.   - C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2
.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2.rb
:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:72:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:70:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:59:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:59:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.r
b:132:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/project/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>
'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/co
mmands.rb:76:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/co
mmands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/co
mmands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/co
mmands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: can you please edit that stacktrace to a more readable form?

Comment: did you install `mysql2` gem successfully and mysql-server,mysql-client?

Comment: possible duplicate of [193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application error with Ruby (1.9.3) on Rails(3.2.3) with MySQL(5.5) on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468118/193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-error-with-ruby-1-9-3-on-rails3-2-3)

Comment: and here;s one more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208029/193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-bug-with-a-new-rails-application

Comment: may be you are running on a 32 bit machine and you sought to install a 64bit mysql gem

Comment: how to install 64bit gem? @Raghu

Comment: @RajarshiDas Whats is mysql-server and mysql-client?

Comment: @Raghu how to install 64bit gem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute 
`rake db:create` 
 
command to create database and paste the errors if any.
 *There we can find meaningful error message*

Comment: hey i cant start my server itself than how to rake db?

Comment: actually there is a problem with your mysql rails configuration. So if you attempt to create database it will display what the problem is. So that we can go further to get the solution.