# Error while starting my Rails server

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I installed everything needed for `rails` applications but when I tried to start `rails` application by running `rails server` I get this error. Can any one please explain what this error is, and provide a solution for this problem

```
C:\Ruby200-x64\pro>rails server
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `requir
e': 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.   - C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2
.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2.rb
:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:72:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:70:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:70:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:59:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:59:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.r
b:132:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/pro/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/co
mmands.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/co
mmands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/co
mmands.rb:73:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/co
mmands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: your mysql2 gem is not installed properly. search stackoverflow for solutions.

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9183708/1075006

Comment: nope not working please help me

Comment: @Bala how to install mysql2 gem properly

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740868/mysql2-gem-compiled-for-wrong-mysql-client-library

Comment: looks like it is a x64 vs. x32 issue. maybe this answers might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208029/193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-bug-with-a-new-rails-application