# ruby server not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server

**As soon as I try to start rails server I encounter following problem. Can anybody please help.**

```
E:\sites\simple_cms>rails s
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `require': 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.   - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-min
gw32/lib/mysql2/1.9/mysql2.so (LoadError) 
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-  mingw3  2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:7:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
    from E:/sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Check out this blog post http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/

Comment: You can visit below URL

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208029/193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-bug-with-a-new-rails-application